# Nuxeo automation and a custom enricher

Tags: nuxeo

I'm trying to learn how to develop my own enricher (I believe I do understand the basic, in terms of how enrichers relate to automation chains and so on). However, I'm having problems:

- I can use existing enrichers with, for example,
  Document.FetchByProperty and everything will work
- But once I include my own custom enricher, I get the error (link below)
- I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong, so I've took existing custom enricher from Nuxeo sample project, and got the same error

Any help is welcome!

Log link: https://answers.nuxeo.com/api/files/2b14d403-aa8a-4ac3-81ca-c9ee13623c2a

I've also asked the same question here:

https://answers.nuxeo.com/general/q/af5a6369c91942b5a81bf61549b467f2/Automation-and-a-custom-enricher

Comment: Can you show us the code of your enricher? And what is the Nuxeo platform version where you are testing it?

Comment: Version is 9.2. I've used the sample enricher found here to make sure it's not something I wrote. https://github.com/nuxeo/nuxeo-sample-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are compiling the enricher code with the same version of Nuxeo libraries as is the version of the target platform.

For example sample project is using the latest version (currently 11.1-SNAPSHOT) and the result code will not be compatible with Nuxeo platform 9.2. Especially abstract methods can have problems.

So there should be this section in *pom.xml* with `<version>9.2</version>` in your case:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.nuxeo</groupId>
    <artifactId>nuxeo-addons-parent</artifactId>
    <version>9.2</version>
</parent>
```

The reason why the `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` is thrown here is in `JsonGenerator`. Nuxeo 9.2 uses `org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator` while newer Nuxe versions use `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator`.

Then this method signature (in 9.2):

```
public void write(org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, DocumentModel documentModel) throws IOException;
```

... is not compatible with this (in 10.3 for example):

```
public void write(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator json, DocumentModel document) throws IOException;
```

And Java is then not able to find correct `write()` method implementation and throws `AbstractMethodError`.

Comment: Thank you, I've completely missed the versions part of the deal.